# authorisation is not available check polkit running and reboots

Tags: linux, rhel

Issue with one of my hosts running RHES7.7 as below

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
I have two hosts running RHES7.7. One of them encountered this issue after reboot. Sending message

```
authorisation is not available check polkit running
```

This basically means network service etc is not running as well. So I can only access this host through console. I can log in after giving root password for maintenance and data etc is there. I tried to start polkit with systemctl restart polkit but just fails with the above message and reboots. Appreciate any advice.

P.S. When I ran `journalctl -u polkit`, I got "no entries"!

Thanks

**update**

This is the error I am getting

[image]

thanks please find the outputs requested. sorry i can only access the host through the console

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl list-units --state=failed`? If you run `grep -r rtl_pci /etc/modprobe.d`, what do you get? And also please show the output of `lsblk` and the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file. Please **edit your question** to add this information, don't add it into comments.

Comment: Many thanks. I trust you can see the snapshots in the main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authorisation is not available check polkit running` is a red herring: the system appears to have dropped into emergency mode, where only very minimal system services are running. In this state, having `polkit.service` not running is normal and expected.

---

The first listed error message is from the kernel:

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 122124
```

is about Nouveau, the open-source NVidia GPU driver. Have you been using it, or the proprietary (closed-source) driver from NVidia? What graphics hardware does your host have?

It is possible (even likely, see below) that this message is not related to your current problem. It might be just "noise" particular to your specific hardware and its current state of driver support.

---

The second message is from `systemd-udevd`:

```
Error running install command for rtl_pci
```

This is self-inflicted, as you have `install rtl_pci /bin/false` in your `/etc/modprobe.d/local-blacklist.conf` to prevent the `rtl_pci` module from loading: it causes the error message as a side effect.

If you want to get rid of the error message, you could replace the `/bin/false` in `local-blacklist.conf` with `/bin/true`. That would tell the system that leaving the module unloaded is not an error.

---

The third message might be the reason your system is dropping into emergency mode. It is from `systemd`, and after decoding the hexadecimal escapes, it looks like this:

```
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by-label-\/apps.device.
```

That refers to `/dev/disk/by-label/\/apps`, or in other words, a filesystem with label `/apps`. According to your `/etc/fstab`, it should be an ext4-type filesystem that's supposed to be mounted to `/apps`.

All the other filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` have been successfully mounted, except `/apps`. And based on your `lsblk` output, it seems it could only be at `/dev/sdd` - there is no other device that is likely to contain an unmounted ext4 filesystem.

But according to `lsblk`, that disk has no partitions - have you initialized the whole disk as a single filesystem? If not, it's possible the disk's partition table may have been corrupted/overwritten, or the disk may have failed.

`systemctl status apps.mount` and/or `journalctl -u apps.mount` might provide more information on what went wrong with the mount attempt.

Unlike earlier RHEL releases with different init systems, the `systemd`-based RHEL 7.x will drop into emergency mode if any filesystem listed in `/etc/fstab` fails to mount, unless that filesystem has the `noauto` or `nofail` mount option. So the failure to mount `/apps` is the most likely reason the system is dropping into emergency mode.

You might temporarily comment out the last line of `/etc/fstab` and reboot to get the system into a more normal state: that should make further diagnosis and recovery easier.

---

You might want to start troubleshooting `/dev/sdd` by first verifying its health with `smartctl -x /dev/sdd`. If it indicates the disk is failing, it's definitely time to  order a new disk and ideally plan on restoring `/apps` from a good backup. But if `smartctl` does not indicate the disk as failing, it might not be the whole truth: disks can fail in ways `smartctl` cannot always detect.

(If you don't have a good backup, and the data on `/apps` has significant value, it is time to decide whether you want to use professional data recovery services, or to try and recover the data yourself. )

If you know `/dev/sdd` should have a partition table, `testdisk` might be a good tool for trying to recover it:

```
yum install epel-release
yum update
yum install testdisk
testdisk /dev/sdd
```

If you know for certain that the whole disk `/dev/sdd` has been initialized as a single ext4 filesystem, you might try

```
e2fsck -C0 /dev/sdd
```

If the tool starts asking you questions (indicating there's a problem it cannot reliably fix automatically), you should abort the check and create an image of the disk first.

**Note:** this command *assumes* that the device you point it at *should* contain an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, and acts accordingly. If it does not find a valid superblock, it might be because the beginning of the disk has been corrupted or overwritten... or because the filesystem simply does not start at the beginning of the disk.

If you are uncertain, or if the disk shows any symptoms of hardware failure, your first priority should be to try and image the failing disk ASAP using [`ddrescue`](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/d/ddrescue-1.27-1.el7.x86_64.html) or a similar tool. You'll also need another disk of suitable size to store the image of the potentially-failing disk.

Comment: Excellent analysis. indeed /apps was the cause of the issue. I removed it from /etc/fstab and reboot did the job. I had a problem with sdd disk so /dev/sdd  throwing errors. I used echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/delete to remove it and then deleted the whole partition. /dev/sdd was not used at all.

Comment: e2fsck -C0 /dev/sdd
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

Comment: I guess there is an issue with that unused /dev/sdd device so I leave it for now. I believe it is a hardware error causing the problem?

Comment: That's possible. Check the `dmesg` output to see if attempts to access `/dev/sdd` have produced any I/O error messages. Note that `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/delete` is only effective until the next reboot or other rescan of the relevant storage bus. Do you know what was the purpose of `/apps`, and if it was intentionally removed recently? If you know it was intentionally removed, then it looks like the `/etc/fstab` line was just forgotten and not cleaned up - with `systemd`, such clean-up when filesystems are removed is more important than before.

Comment: You are correct. I removed that partition (entire disk) with fdisk /dev/sdd because of annoying I/O errors.  There was some stale data for an old application called sybase. Fortunately this still exists in my other host rhes75 that I had it first. The files are there 
sybase@rhes75:SYB_157 /apps> df -k .
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda13     206292968 43671804 152119020  23% /apps

dmesg shows
[ 1553.157735]  sdd:
[ 1655.140080]  sdd:
[ 1836.200895]  sdd:
[root@rhes76 apps]# su - sybase
Last login: Tue Oct 12 23:08:03 BST 2021 on pts/2

Comment: [ 1553.157735]  sdd:
[ 1655.140080]  sdd:
[ 1836.200895]  sdd:
[root@rhes76 apps]# su - sybase
Last login: Tue Oct 12 23:08:03 BST 2021 on pts/2
su: warning: cannot change directory to /apps/sybase: No such file or directory
$ pwd
/apps
. So pretty old stuff

Comment: I am surprised sometimes the message on console more are misleading that the real error itself, sending one on a wild goose chase

Comment: Those annoying I/O errors are usually how a dying disk starts to fail, so it is a good thing that `/dev/sdd` is unused and that the errors stopped when you stopped using `sdd`: it proves the disk is now entirely unused. Since you know it produced errors the last time it was used, it would be a good idea to at least document that the disk is known to be failing, or outright remove it during some suitable maintenance break (non-urgent).

Comment: Thanks. This is the affected disk

Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

A compatible disk will do. 

For now I created a softlink as below

ls -l /apps
/apps -> /data1/apps
and copied the data from the healthy partition on the other host to there